# what to use between [] and {} in Angularjs

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs, object

I need to make multiple objects of same element. I cant figure it out that which should I use between [] and {} to make my data structure.

I am not clear about the difference between [] and {}. 
I am using Angularjs

Comment: What language are you using?

Comment: could you just precise which languare you are using ?

Comment: AngularJS is a JavaScript framework (read the tag) so chances are it's JavaScript indeed.

Comment: I need to know what is the difference between using [] and {} to pass elements in the angularjs javascript controller

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`[]` represents Array

`{}` represents Object

The advantage of using array is the ability to use native functions like `forEach`, `sort`, `split`, `splice` and more.

The advantage of using object is to getting easy way to find specific item from list of items.
For example, if you have a list of objects with unique `ID` for each one 
and you create object that contain them by `ID`:

```
var list = {"123": {ID: 123, ...}, "456": {ID: 456, ...}}
```

Now you can find item by `ID` without searching in all items for this `ID`
just with `list[ID]`

Answer (score 3):

Use `[]` if you want an array a.k.a. a list of objects. Use `{}` if you want to create a single object.

Comment: Might worth noting that object can be also used for arrays with keys other than integers.

Comment: Would you care to elaborate? An object can contain arrays indeed. But it will still not be an array itself.

Comment: If you have string IDs, you can use them as keys of your array object (associative array). See the answer of @ElhayAvichzer